# Converting to a Box<Any>

Tags: rust

I have a `Box<Trait>`, and want to be able to cast it to `Box<Obj>`. There is [BoxAny](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/trait.BoxAny.html) to supposedly do this, but trying to call `t.downcast::<Obj>()` says there's not method `downcast` in scope.

The docs show how to do this if you have a reference. You can just do `&Trait as &Any`. But it doesn't seem to be possible to do `boxedTrait as Box<Any>`.

Here's a [playground](http://is.gd/oe5bvt) showing what I mean.

Comment: You can only convert to `Any` from a concrete type

Comment: This is not as easy as it might seem at first, due to how the vtable stuff actually works, but it can be done; [Teepee’s header representation scheme](https://github.com/teepee/teepee/tree/master/src/httpcommon/headers) is one example of doing it.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I looked through there, and didn't see an instance of converting `Box<Header>` to `Box<Any>`...

Comment: I believe that @ChrisMorgan refers to `mod.rs` file where `Any` is essentially reimplemented along with `Header` trait. This kind of thing is possible only with your traits, unfortunately.

Comment: @seanmonstar: it’s a matter of implementing `Any` for `Trait` so that you can use `.downcast::<Obj>()` on `Box<Trait>`.

Answer (score 1):

`Any` allows downcasting to a concrete type, so you *need* to know this concrete type when you convert to `Box<Any>`. However, you don't know concrete type if you only have a trait object for some other trait - that's exactly the point of trait objects. So you can't go from `Box<SomeTrait>` to `Box<Any>`, it is impossible.

Ideally it should be possible to write something like `Box<Show+Any>`. This would allow using `Show` methods as well as `Any` methods. This is also impossible, however: you can only write lifetime bounds and built-in kinds in additional to the main trait, so `Box<Show+Sync+'a>` is legal, but `Box<Show+Any>` is not.

If you own the trait you want to use with `Any`, then a way to achieve this would be trait inheritance:

```
trait MyTrait : Any {
    // ...
}
```

However, inheritance does not work with trait objects, so you can't invoke `Any` methods on `Box<MyTrait>`. There is a workaround for that which involves reimplementing `Any` (as can be found [here](https://github.com/teepee/teepee/blob/7ef85de23c84642f248922a6b48d16a642669448/src/httpcommon/headers/mod.rs)), but it is anything but pretty.

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a simple way to do this kind of thing. Something like this is likely possible to implement with some unsafe code, probably, but I don't know how.