# How to get reference to struct from boxed trait object?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I want to insert a value of type `Box<T>` into a `Vec<Box<Trait>>` and then get a reference to that value back. (`T` is a generic type that implements `Trait`). The returned value should be of type `&T`

The implementation below almost works, except there is no way to [convert `Box<Trait>` to `Box<Any>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595505/converting-to-a-boxany).

`HashSet` has the (experimental) `get_or_insert()`, which is perfect for this, but there seems to be no version for `Vec`?

```
use std::any::Any;

trait A {}
struct B;
impl A for B {}

// How to write this function?
pub fn insert<'a, T>(vector: &mut Vec<Box<dyn A>>, value: T) -> &'a T where T: A {
    // move the value into the vector
    vector.push(Box::new(value));

    // get the reference to the inserted value back
    let it: &Box<dyn Any> = vector.last().unwrap(); // compile error
    match it.downcast_ref::<T>() {
        Some(i) => i,
        None => panic!(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec: Vec<Box<dyn A>> = Vec::new();
    let b = B;
    let b_ref = insert(&mut vec, b);
    // can't use b here since moved, so need b_ref
}
```

Comment: Worth reading: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/convert-box-dyn-t-to-box-dyn-any/28951/20

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define a helper trait that is implemented for all types like this:

```
pub trait AToAny: 'static {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}

impl<T: 'static> AToAny for T {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}
```

Then require it to be implemented for subtypes of A.

```
pub trait A: AToAny {
}
```

You can now call `.as_any()` on the `&dyn A` you get from the vector.

```
pub fn insert<'a, T: A>(vector: &'a mut Vec<Box<dyn A>>, value: T) -> &'a T {
    vector.push(Box::new(value));

    let it: &dyn Any = vector.last().unwrap().as_any();
    match it.downcast_ref::<T>() {
        Some(i) => i,
        None => panic!(),
    }
}
```